# Athena- Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN date and date

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I created a partition projection in Athena named 'paritiondate', which contains date information in the format `2022/01/01`.

I'm running the following query in Athena (via a grafana plugin) which make use of a grafana/athena macro $__dateFilter. The macro is necessary because it detects the date range in Grafana and updates the BETWEEN clause in the Athena query accordingly:

`SELECT ssl_protocol, count (*) FROM alb_logs_partition WHERE $__dateFilter(partitiondate) LIMIT 5`

The resulting raw query received by Athena is:

`SELECT ssl_protocol, count (*) FROM alb_logs_partition WHERE partitiondate BETWEEN date '2022-01-10' AND date '2022-01-11' LIMIT 5`

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
error querying the database: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:62: Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN date and date.
```

So my understanding is that Athena is rejecting the partitiondate value as it's a varchar, and not date.

I've tried to find a workaround in an attempt to convert it into a date format using date_parse. For example I tried:

`SELECT ssl_protocol, count (*) FROM alb_logs_partition WHERE $__dateFilter(date_parse(partitiondate, '%Y/%m/%d')) LIMIT 5`

However, the macro cannot handle this and throws an error.

Is there any other way I can modify the query to convert partitiondate from a varchar into a format Athena/Presto understands, before then using the value in the $__dateFilter macro?

Comment: "contains date information is in the format 01/01/2022" .... Why are you using different format '%Y/%m/%d' ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I've corrected it, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I found answer. Please, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071320/20887767)